# How to use axios(or fetch) to download a mp4 file and feed it to <video> tag as src attribute value?

Tags: javascript, video, axios, fetch

I am developing a web app and having a url like(this is fake):

http://10.100.100.10:1000/a/b/c/000.mp4?a=1&b=2

And my progress is that when I click abc in the page, browser will download the file or bring up windows player to play the video.
But when I assign ObjectUrl to  tag, it just doesn't work.

Here is my code to download mp4 file.
It is based on vue and axiox, but they are not limitation.
PS: I use webpack devServer.proxy to solve cors problem but I don't think that's a problem.

```
<template>
    <div @click="mao">abc</div>
<template>

<script>
    methods: {
        mao: function(){
            const vm = this;
            const url = "/a/b/c/000.mp4?a=1&b=2";
            this.axios({
                url,
                method: "GET",
                responseType: "blob"
            })
            .then(res => {
                const filename = "111.mp4";
                const url = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([res.data]));
                const link = document.createElement("a");
                link.href = url;
                link.setAttribute("download", filename);
                link.setAttribute("id", "tmp");
                document.body.appendChild(link);
                link.click();
                return link;
            })
            .then(link => {
                document.body.removeChild(link);
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: When you put `const url` in browser's address bar does it play a video (as if it's a direct link to some mp4 file)?

Answer (score -1):

Just curious, any reason why download the whole file (and download to where? inside the client OS?) instead of streaming the source instead?

I have updated this post with a sample for streaming MP4.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<body> 

<video width="400" controls>
  <source src="https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>

</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: Right now download to client OS. Downloading is not my purpose but where as far as I can get. I hope to streaming the source but I don't know how to achieve it for video tag.

Comment: Since streaming is your ideal solution, you can try it with the HTML5 video tag. I have updated my post so you can take a look there.

Comment: @Norman I tried this, but doesn't work. Could you help me out on my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62291888/how-to-stream-mp4-videos-from-django-3-to-vue-js